# Footnote separator line appears in the wrong side of the page

Tags: footnotes, citing

I'm writing my Master's thesis and so far, no big problems. Now I have this issue with the footnote separator line at the beginning of one chapter, only on this page: it appears on the right instead of on the left, like in the rest of the pages. 
What can it be? I'm using

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{scrreprt}
```

**UPDATE!** I discovered The problem! It happens when the next section begins in the following page with an epigraph. If the `\section{name}` and the epigraph are in the same page where the `\footnote` is, then there is no problem.

Still, if someone knows how to avoid deleting or adding text so that the-same-page-situation happens... I'm all ears!

Comment: give at least a screenshot of the problem if you are not able to create a minimal working example.

Comment: why do you need `\cleardoublepage` ? in most document classes `\chapter` would do that automatically.